# updating maradns with nsupdate

Tags: openwrt

I have configured Maradns as dns server on openwrt platform. Can i use nsupdate as ddns client to update the DNS Server. Is it possible of updating Maradns zones with nsupdate.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [maradns documentation](http://www.maradns.org/notes.html). My reading of it is that no you cannot. However it does have something called fetchzone.